# How to do this: embedded USB-Host communication with plugged USB-Device

Tags: c, usb, arm, host, atmel

I am currently practising with USB programming on an AT91SAM9G20-Evaluation Kit. I learned much about USB devices and USB device port drivers while "playing" with the ATMEL provided USB device port projects (CDC-driver, ..).

But now I'd like to write a small driver to controll a wireless stick
which I plugged into one of the boards USB-A Host Ports.

I read a lot on Stack Overflow, the OpenHCI specification and even found some libraries on the net, but I am not sure if it's a good way to implement my own stack without any "good" knowledge in USB Host Port programming.

Is there a small and easy way to control the wireless-stick at the boards USB Host port? (like using the USART-Interfaces?).

I am also keen to hear hints on how to implement RTUSB or libUSB in to the AT91.

Answer (score 0):

You can download AT91LIB version 1.9 from atmel from this [page](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AT91SAMSOFTWAREPACKAGE.aspx)

The usb host libraries are under at91lib/usb/host.  They're not the complete package you need though since they're just the OHCI driver -- you still need a USB driver and class drivers to implement what you want.

You could try an RTOS with USB Host support like [rt-usb32](http://www.on-time.com/rtusb-32.htm)